# Can't fix X in command line for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I just started to learn Python and am using the Jupyter Notebook to write code. I'm unsure how to fix this problem. Every time I type into the command line 'x' it brings the x to the beginning of the command line.

for example:

If I want to type

```
x1=5
print(x1)
```

it becomes

```
x1=5
xprint(1
```

The moment I type in <kbd>x</kbd> it brings it to the front of the command line! I'm unsure how and why this is happening and how to fix it. This doesn't happen with any other letters such as <kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>z</kbd>. It only happens when I type in <kbd>x</kbd>.

Comment: It seems that pressing `x` key inserts a *pair of keys* `Home`, `x`. To be sure that this behavior is only in Jupyter Notebook, try writing the same text in other program, e. g. in some text editor.

Comment: @MarianD If it is just within Jupyter Notebook, how would i resolve the issue?

Comment: Try creating another notebook in Jupyter Notebook and writing in it. If it is still so bad, try writing in other part of that browser (as Jupyter Notebook is hosted in your default web browser) to exclude the possibility of inheriting this strange behavior from it. You may also try other web browser.

Comment: @MarianD That worked, thank you.